# optional characters in javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to build a regular expression in javascript that checks for 3 word characters however 2 of them are are optional.  So I have:

`/^\w\w\w/i`

what I am stumped on is how to make it that the user does not have to enter the last two letters but if they do they have to be letters

Comment: Does `/^\w\w?\w?$/i` work for you?

Comment: I did have to change it to \d and \Dbecause cause of the data i was testing but the answers were still correct about the optional characters

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this regular expression:

```
/^\w{1,3}$/i
```

The quantifier `{1,3}` means to repeat the preceding expression (`\w`) at least 1 and at most 3 times. Additionally, `$` marks the end of the string similar to `^` for the start of the string. Note that `\w` does not just contain the characters `a`–`z` and their uppercase counterparts (so you don’t need to use the *i* modifier to make the expression case insensitive) but also the digits `0`–`9` and the low line character `_`.

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
/^\w\w?\w?$/i
```

The `?` marks the preceding expression as optional.

The `$` is necessary to anchor the end of the regex.
Without the `$`, it would match `a12`, because it would only match the first character.  The `$` forces the regex to match the entire string.